# Facebook like plugin getelements thwarted

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I got the javascript into the header but our CMS (meh don't ask) is stripping the elements and their tags which are needed to style the damn thing. How can I hard code them into the script?

I end up with:  `<div class="fb-like"></div>`

Instead of: `<div class="fb-like" data-layout="button_count" data-width="200" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

I don't know code well enough to just hard code them in:

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```